# I can't open the file exported by the PhpSpreadsheet library in Excel

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Criei uma exportação em Excel de uma tabela do meu banco de dados, eu consigo baixar o arquivo, mas o Excel não abre, consigo abrir no Libreoffice Calc normalmente.

I tried to create an export of a table from PostgreSQL, but Excel won't open the file

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["users"])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Carregue o arquivo autoload.php do Composer

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

// Adicione aqui o código para conexão com o banco de dados, se necessário
$host = "";
$port = "";
$dbname = "";
$user = "";
$password = "";

// Consulta para obter os produtos selecionados da tabela 'tabela_selecionados'
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabela_selecionados";

// Executar a consulta no banco de dados
$conn = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$password");
$result = pg_query($conn, $query);

if (!$result) {
    die("Erro ao consultar os produtos selecionados: " . pg_last_error());
}

// Verificar se há produtos selecionados
if (pg_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<h1 class='p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white'>Produtos Selecionados</h1>";
    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>CODIGO</th>";
    echo "<th>FOB ATUAL</th>";
    echo "<th>CODIGO CHINA</th>";
    echo "<th>NOME</th>";
    echo "<th>DATA FOB</th>";
    echo "<th>ANO</th>";
    echo "<th>OBSERVACAO</th>"; // Adicione a coluna de observação
    echo "</tr>";

    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row["cod_bbr"]) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row["fob_atual"]) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row["cod_a"]) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row["nome"]) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row["data_fob"]) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row["ano"]) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row["obs"]) . "</td>"; // Exibe a observação
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";

    // Fechar a conexão com o banco de dados
    pg_close($conn);

    // Crie uma planilha
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

// Preencha a planilha com os produtos selecionados
$rowIndex = 1; // Índice para controlar as linhas da planilha

// Cabeçalho da planilha
$sheet->setCellValue('A'.$rowIndex, 'CODIGO');
$sheet->setCellValue('B'.$rowIndex, 'FOB ATUAL');
$sheet->setCellValue('C'.$rowIndex, 'CODIGO CHINA');
$sheet->setCellValue('D'.$rowIndex, 'NOME');
$sheet->setCellValue('E'.$rowIndex, 'DATA FOB');
$sheet->setCellValue('F'.$rowIndex, 'ANO');
$sheet->setCellValue('G'.$rowIndex, 'OBSERVACAO');

while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rowIndex++;
    $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$rowIndex, $row["cod_bbr"]);
    $sheet->setCellValueExplicit('B'.$rowIndex, $row["fob_atual"]);
    $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$rowIndex, $row["cod_a"]);
    $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$rowIndex, $row["nome"]);
    $sheet->setCellValue('E'.$rowIndex, $row["data_fob"]);
    $sheet->setCellValue('F'.$rowIndex, $row["ano"]);
    $sheet->setCellValue('G'.$rowIndex, $row["obs"]);
}

// Defina o cabeçalho do arquivo para que seja baixado como um arquivo Excel
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;'); // Defina o conjunto de caracteres como UTF-8
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="produtos_selecionados.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

// Crie um gravador para escrever a planilha em um arquivo
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('php://output');

} else {
    echo "<h1>Nenhum produto selecionado.</h1>";
}
?>
```

Configuration of fields in my database.  [cod_a] character varying(120) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"  [nome] character varying(600) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",  [cod_bbr] character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",  [fob_atual] numeric(10,2),  [data_fob] character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default", [ ano] character varying(8) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",  [obs] character varying(600) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"  o banco de dados he database is encoded as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HITtb.png) If anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

resolved!
The issue you are facing with the corrupted file could be related to a mixture of HTML and Excel output in the same file. When you use echo to display HTML content and then try to export to Excel using PhpSpreadsheet, Excel may misinterpret the file and display it as corrupt.

To resolve this issue, you can separate the Excel spreadsheet export from the displayed HTML content. One way to do this is to use the header() function to define the type of content being sent to the browser. You can also create a link or button in the HTML for the user to click to download the Excel spreadsheet.

Here is a modification to your code to perform the correct export: